# Only type-check an Ocaml file

Tags: ocaml, typechecking

I am wondering is it possible to only type-check an ml file? More precisely, I have a file `a.ml` that depends on `b.cmi`. How can I only type-check `a.ml`? Note that I don't have `b.cmo`, only `b.cmi`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ocamlc -i a.ml` should work; it also returns the inferred interface.

Note that even if you don't have `b.cmo`, you can perfectly *compile* `a.ml` (this is what separate compilation is about) with `ocamlc -c a.ml`.